# Array of objects as an input parameter in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to describe the following post parameter in swagger:

```
{
    "sources": [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "parentId": 201
        },{
            "id": 102,
            "parentId": 201
        },{
            "id": 102,
            "parentId": 202
        }
    ],
    "destinationId": 301,
    "param1": "value 1",
    "param2": "value 2",
}
```

The issue is that the `sources` is an array of objects, that swagger does not seem to support. Here is what I tried:

```
paths:
    /bulk-action:
        post:
            parameters:
                - name: sources
                  in: formData
                  type: array
                  enum:
                      $ref: '#/definitions/BulkSource'
                - name: destinationId
                  in: formData
                  type: integer
                - name: param1
                  in: formData
                  type: string
                - name: param2
                  in: formData
                  type: string
definitions:
    BulkSource:
        type: object
        properties:
            id:
                type: integer
            parentId:
                type: integer
```

Any idea on how to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your request body to post is a `json` object instead of `form`. In such case, your swagger document need to be modified as follows:

1. When request body is json, a parameter with `in: body` is used instead of multiple parameters of `in: formData`.
2. If `in` is `body`, a `schema` object is required.
3. Defined the json properties under `schema`. If the property `type` is `array`, `items` object is required.

Following is an example:

```
paths:
  /bulk-action:
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          schema:
            properties:
              sources:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/definitions/BulkSource'
              destinationdId:
                type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
definitions:
  BulkSource:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      parentId:
        type: integer
```

Comment: could you please tell me where you are making these changes. Or what I want to ask is, in which file the above code is written. I am unable to find the above code in my swagger API.

Comment: What if my request body' array does not have the title or name similar to 'Sources' present in the OP body???? I have similar problem, only my request body does not have the name of array. It is more similar to 
[
      { key: value, 
        key: value
      }, {
        key: value, 
        key: value
      }
]

Comment: @Rishikesh have you figured out how to do that?

Comment: @esh Yes, I figured it for OpenApi 3.0.1, you just have to ignore the title or name and continue with the type field. For 2.0, I still haven't got any solution...

Comment: @Wilson can you assist me with this. am trying to collect form array in swaggerPHP, dont know how to define it so swagger can render it well,

Comment: @Rishikesh just use schema with the reference to the object of array type:    
`
      - in: "body"
        name: "param"
        schema: 
          $ref: "#/definitions/ArrayObject"

definitions:
  ArrayObject:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: "#/definitions/ArrayElement"
`